# display latest bill month

Tags: sql

I have t_cust table and I want to display customer's latest bill month and bill amount.
I have written query but for large data it will take much time.Is there any simple 
logic to find latest bill month?

```
create table t_cust
(
cust_id     varchar2(3),
b_year      varchar2(4),
b_month     varchar2(2),
b_amount    number
);

insert into t_cust values('ABC','2015','11',100);
insert into t_cust values('ABC','2015','12',200);
insert into t_cust values('ABC','2016','01',300);
insert into t_cust values('XYZ','2016','01',1000);
insert into t_cust values('XYZ','2016','02',2000);
insert into t_cust values('XYZ','2016','03',3000);

commit;

    select cust_id,substr(to_date(b_year*100+b_month,'YYYYMM'),4)latest_bill_mth,b_amount bill_amount
    from   t_cust
    where  (cust_id,b_year*100+b_month) in (
                                            select cust_id,max(b_year*100+b_month)
                        from   t_cust
                        group by cust_id
                        );
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Oracle, so simply use a ROW_NUMBER/RANK:

```
select ...
from
 (
   select ...
      ,row_number() 
       over (partition by t_cust
             order by year desc, month desc) as rn
 ) dt
where rn = 1
```